# Constructor with Optional<String>

Tags: java, constructor, option-type

I have written the following code:

```
void Test(A a) {
   B b = new B(a.getName());
}
```

So, the constructor of `B` expects a `String`. It looks like the following:

```
protected B (String name) {
    super(name, KIND);
    this.name = name;
}
```

But `a.getName()` gives me a name with `Optional<String>` as return value and I do not want to change that. Therefore, I try to change the parameter of the constructor `B` (I replace `String name` with `Optional<String>`), but then Eclipse underlines `super(name, KIND)` and  `this.name = name` with red and Eclipse recommends to change the parameter of the constructor again to `String  name`.

How can I solve it?

best regards,

Comment: Just call the `get()` on the `Optional`, i.e `a.getName().get()`. How you deal with the `null`s is up to you (see [`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--)). Read more about the `Optional` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--).

Comment: wow, thanks for that. I did not know that. The only thing what I tried was to cast it, so (String)a.getName() but I did not work because you can not cast from Optional<String> to String. The advice with the additional get() helps. Thank you !

Comment: You're going from `String name` to `Optional<String> name`, so not only change the constructor (or better yet make another), you'll have to change the variable type from `String` to `Optional<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

An `Optional<String>` *might* contain a `String`, so you need to check for that (and generally speaking, handle the case where it is absent).  So your `Test()` method might look like this:

```
void Test(A a){
 // Consider adding a a.getName().isPresent() check and handling the false
 // case if you need to.  Otherwise you'll get an IllegalStateException.
 B b = new B (a.getName().get());
}
```

In general, the better practice is to leave your constructor parameter as a `String`, and then convert it into a n `Optional<String>` when you store it.

The alternative, if you really want users to pass in `Optional`s, which does sometimes make sense, is to fix the `super()` constructor to also take an `Optional<String>`.  If you can't do that, you need to similarly call `.get()` and pass the resulting `String` into `super()`; again handling the absent case as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could make another constructor that takes aan Optional.