# JavaBean with java.util.Optional

Tags: java, javabeans, option-type

I want to make use of the new java.util.Optional in my beans.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528143/constructor-with-optionalstring) the attributes should be passed to the constructor as simple types, like this:

```
class Foo {
    Optional<A> optionalA;

    public Foo(A a){
        optionalA = Optional.ofNullable(a);
    }
}
```

but, what about the setter method for the attribute?

should it be:

```
public void setOptinalA(Optional<A> newOptionalA){
    optionalA = newOptionalA;
}
```

or:

```
public void setOptinalA(A newA){
        optionalA = Optional.ofNullable(newA);
    }
```

are the two of them compliant with the JavaBean specification?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's probably compliant, but [don't do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/829571).

Comment: Many thanks for the advice.